# Bootstrap 4 sidebar layout not aligning well

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

Working on an Angular SPA whereby am using bootstrap as my css framework. I have created different components and included them in the main app.component.html file. All are aligned properly except the bootstrap 4 sidebar,, I need it to be fixed and should be on the far-left of the screen.

The problem is that it pushes the main body down..

```html
<!--Include Navbar which works well-->
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<div class="container">
  <!-- include sidebar-->
  <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <nav id="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-header">
      <h3>Bootstrap Sidebar</h3>
    </div>

    <ul class="list-unstyled components">
      <p>Dummy Heading</p>
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Home 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Home 2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Home 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Pages</a>
        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Page 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Page 2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Page 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</div>
```

Comment: how does your css look like? if you want it fixed to the left `position:fixed` may provide that.

Comment: Add all of your HTML code in this page.